# Problem with GORM Lazy Loaded List

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm currently experiencing an issue with grails. I have a class (Item) containing a List (hasMany = [users : User]), then User is a class containing 3 sub classes (SubUser1, SubUser2).

The problem is when I touch the collection containing the list of users, then the objects contained there are all of type User (and not of the sub class, which should be the correct one).

With this issue is impossible to know, of which type the user in the collection is.

Have you experienced this issue before? Do you know how to fix this?

Thanks,
Nicolas

Here is the relevant piece of code:

```
/*** Domain Class ***/
class Item {
   List<User> users = []
   static hasMany = [users : User]
}

class User {
   String username
}

class User1 {
   //Some other properties
} 

/*** On the view ***/
item.users
     --> Returns a list of User_$javassist$ and 
     not of type User1 as it should be
```

Comment: Could you please share the code to access users through Item class and how to decide they are user object but not sub classes.

Comment: At the moment, to see the real class of the objects on the list, I'm just iterating through the collection and loading each of these objects again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project that uses polymorphism like this in grails. And i don't have this problem. I have a superclass of name `Media` and and subclasses like `Book` and `Movie`

if i do a `Media.all.each { it instanceof Movie ? println 'is movie' : 'is not movie' }` would give me the expected output where some is movie and some is not movie.

**EDIT**

Try this structure instead

```
class Item {
   static hasMany = [users : User]
   static mapping = {
       tablePerHierarchy false
   }

}

class User {
   String username
}

class User1 extends User {
   //Some other properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Do you know which version you are currently using? (I'm using 1.3.6)

Comment: Also, I just checked, User.all() works correctly. 

The problem seems to ocurre when I try to load the user list for the item class.

Comment: maybe you need eager fetching?

Comment: I already tried it, without any effect.

I ended up just loading the object in the collection before using it. But it is just a dirty Hack which may hurt the application performance.

Comment: Maybe if i can see your class structure, i might be able to help you further.

Comment: you can remove `List<User> users = []` this is not needed. and might be the culprit.

Comment: I cant see that you have a superclass on your User classes... the way it is set up now, only `User` can belong to the users set.

Comment: @netbrain
So, tried removing the List<User> from the Item class.

Also did on the view an g:each for the collection and then a ${user.class}

Really weird is that, some of the classes there are of type User_$javassist$, while some others are of the actual Type User1. Altough there are no User classes on the database (At the moment there is no entry fo class User, only subclasses of it)

Comment: if you do a user.username in the g:each do you get an exception or does it resolve the properties correctly?

Comment: It resolves it correctly. Even if I call a property that is only available on the subclass! It's a really weird behavior. It seems as if the proxy around the class would be wrong, but the object inside it right.

Comment: Has probably something to do with you doing this in the view. if you tried `println user.list.each { it.class }` in the controller. It would probably give you the expected class.

Comment: @netbrain, just tested it into the controller, again only got the superclass (User_$$_javassist_) instead of the right class. Not even instanceof recognizes the right class. Any other idea?

Comment: does this also give javaassist ? `println User.all.each { it.class }`

Comment: try adding 
`tablePerHierarchy false` as stated in my answer above.

Comment: Yes, and yes (I tested already both of them) I think this is a bug, will report this into grails! Thanks for your help anyway!